# Phaser play animations at the same time

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I currently have a group of sprites that the player can add to when they click. I want to find a way to make it so that they play the animation at the same time (which is important since otherwise the conveyor belts will be out of sync). I've tried to do `conveyors.playAnimation()` every time it adds something new, but that resulted in it "skipping" frames every time I add a new one. Is there a method I could use so that the new one starts at the same frame as the others?

Comment: Did my answer help? Do you need somemore assistance, or could you find a better solution?

Comment: Sorry, yeah, it helped. Unfortunately, it wasn’t exactly what I was looking for, but it was good enough for my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can start an animation, *mid animation*, but you could do something like this. This would sync the animation after max 1 second:

1. calculate the `delay` to the next *"animation start"*
2. add a new Sprite, to the `Group`
3. *"restart"* all sprites after the `delay`

This should create a smooth transition and startup, after a small delay only for the new sprite *(it could be optimzied).*

**Here is a short demo:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        preload,
        create
    }
}; 

let group;

function preload(){
  this.load.path = 'http://labs.phaser.io/assets/sprites/';
  this.load.spritesheet('gem', 'diamonds32x24x5.png', 
    { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 24 });
}

function create () {
    this.add.text(10, 10, 'Just Click to add')
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

     const animConfig = {
        key: 'flash',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('gem', { end: 4 }),
        frameRate: 5,
        repeat: -1
     };

     this.anims.create(animConfig);

     group = this.add.group();
     group.create(32, 64);

     this.anims.play('flash', group.getChildren());

     this.input.on('pointerdown', p => {
        let spriteAnims = group.children.entries[0].anims;
        let delay = spriteAnims.duration * ( 1 - spriteAnims.getProgress());
        group.create(p.x, p.y, spriteAnims.currentFrame.textureKey);
        this.time.addEvent({ 
          delay, 
          callback: () => this.anims.play('flash', group.getChildren())
        });
    }, this);
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```